Do epistemic oughts exist?
Are there any notions of what one should or ought to believe given a certain piece of evidence?
For example, if I hear a noise outside the window, should I now update my credence in there being a murderer outside my house, even if this update is very insignificant? Or should I not?
Should I even represent beliefs as degrees or should they be ternary? (I.e. belief, disbelief, and suspension of belief)

You should update your beliefs or credence in them when you have good reason to do so.

Epistemic soundness is a value. Whatever moral system you are considering, one ought to do what the system values. However depending on the system epistemic soundness will be considered more or less important. Cults value adhesion to the group's belief more than evidence, and members who follow evidence against the dogma are usually admonished, rejected and shunned. Maybe "what are the moral systems that say we ought to follow evidence?" or "do we ought to follow evidence in moral system X?" would be better formulations for your question.

Try putting ifs after your oughts.

Arguably, there are oughts relating to how you form your beliefs, how you update them, and how strongly you adhere to them. This is the subject of virtue epsistemology. But the question of what subjects you choose to form beliefs about is interest-relative.

Does this answer your question? Are You Blameworthy for "reasoning incorrectly"

Maybe related/good jumping-off points: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-utility/ and https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dutch-book/ . Those are both attempts to argue that one should have consistent beliefs, which I think one can potentially try to extend to whether or not one should update one's credence in light of evidence.

Unfortunately, no -- and at several levels.
Even if we assume a fixed set of background assumptions, the field of statistics shows that a Bayesian vs frequentist vs likelihood frameworks can give different answers to "what ought we to infer from the data?"
Stepping back, we have the Duhem-Quine Thesis of the underdetermination of scientific theories, so even if we all adhered to the same inferential framework and priors, we'd still be forced to decide what hypotheses to keep vs modify in cases where we have dis-confirmatory evidence.
So, there is no strict sense of "ought" in inference. However, there is "common sense" inference of the kind used in legal discussions, where we do actually try to argue what you ought to have concluded in a particular situation (e.g., negligence claims, tort law, malpractice etc).

@DikranMarsupial - not really, even the asymptotic guarantees of convergence doesn't get us to ought. Frequentists select p-values, bayesians posterior credibilites and priors. IF they happen to agree then I think we'd have a happy situation where a Frequentist and Bayesian would both say we ought to infer something. But as my second paragraph shows, even if statisticians all agreed on oughts for every hypothesis test, we'd still be stuck in theoretical underdetermination .. empiricism and certainty don't go together unfortunately..

@DikranMarsupial -- agree on epistemic probabiltiy wrt bayes vs frequentist philosophy.  Don't want to get too far into phil of stats. We use statistics to make inferences - bayesians use degrees of belief, and frequentists focus on severity and error control (per Mayo). Regardless, we can frame all inference using decision theory and the act of believing/accepting/not accepting etc as implictly an ought (e.g., if p-val > 0.05 we ought not reject the null). I agree there are more nuances here but justpointing out there are many ways to use data to get inferences.

@DikranMarsupial The reason I mentioned statistics is because its a well defined area where you would think we could appeal to for epistemic oughts but I was simply explaining the even here we don't get to oughts. I think step back and say even if within a fixed theory we could get oughts from statistics, we would still be faced with the underdetermination issue.
The "ought" here is related specifically to what ought I to infer given this data. The fact that diff schools answer diff things misses the point of bringing up statistics.

@DikranMarsupial I do agree with this statement "frequentists cannot assign a probability to the truth of a proposition, so with a frequentist null hypothesis test there is no mathematical/logical connection between the p-value and the probability that the null hypothesis is false." However, I don't think that frequentists would say this prevents them from reasoning about hypotheses - they can still say, epistemically, I outght not reject the null, or I ought to reject the null, based on what I've learned from the data.

@DikranMarsupial its just that Bayesian's and frequentist approaches use probability at different places (I've used both approaches in my own work), and so can give different views to "ought". Even within boring ol' NHST, oughts are subjectively set by p-value cutoffs.

@DikranMarsupial -- OK, but people do take it as potentially prescriptive "ought" anyway. I'm not debating different views of proper stats practice, but people use both systems to try to answer the same questions (whether you and I agree that is correct or not). All I'm trying to show is that even within a theory, the choice of inference methods will differ in what one ought to conclude. Bayesians things frequentists are making logical errors, but nonetheless both camps can come to different conclusions about whether the data support the hyopthesis.

There is nothing special about epistemics regarding whether oughts can exist. Whatever theory one uses to generally determine oughts would apply equally to oughts relating to beliefs.
So yes, epistemic oughts do exist, and differ between moral systems.
